# Curried anonymous function in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have the function below and it works:

```
(fn x => x * 2) 2;
```

but this one doesn't work:

```
(fn x y => x + y ) 2 3;
```

Can anyone tell me why? Or give me some hint to get it to work?

Comment: it works when I changed to this
(fn (x,y) => x + y) (2,3);

but why (fn x y => x * y) 2 3; produces an error

Answer (score 35):

`(fn x => fn y => x+y) 2 3;` works. `fn` simply doesn't have the same syntactic sugar to define curried functions that `fun` has.

Answer (score 3):

In Standard ML, a function can have only **one argument**, so use

```
(fn (x,y) => x + y) (2,3)
```

and the type is

```
fn: int * int -> int
```

in this time (x,y) and (2,3) is a list structure,

Comment: but that changes it to an uncurried function, which is different

Comment: Oh, currying! Sorry, I didn't catch the problem, sepp2k's answer is good.

Comment: Also, (2,3) is not a list structure is a tuple of type int * int, which is different from type int list which would be the type of [2,3].

Answer (score 2):

The answers posted above are correct. SML functions take *only* one argument. As a result, SML functions can have only one of two input types :

1) `t = (t1 * t2 * ... * tN)` , for some N

2) `t = a`, for some `a`.

So, technically speaking, SML *only* takes product types *or* unary types as arguments to functions. One can more generally think of this as an Unary-Type or a projection of some product Type.

In order to have currying *inside* anonymous functions, feel free to nest them inside each other as :
`fn x1 => fn x2 => ... fn xN => ...`

I think it's also important to know that :
`fun a = fn x1 => fn x2 => ... fn xN => ...` is the full expansion of the syntactic sugar : `fun a x1 x2 .. xN`