# When should I use val x = fn as opposed to fun x

Tags: function, anonymous-function, sml, ml

I've just started learning Standard ML (and functional programming in general) and I've come across two different ways of defining a function.

```
val double = fn x => x*2:
```

And

```
fun double x = x*2;
```

If I understand correctly, the first one is assigning a variable to an ananonymous function. Under what circumstances should I do this instead of `fun abc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a style question. The `fun` syntax [is syntactic sugar for `fn`](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/03-ml-functions.html), so anything that you can write with the former can also be written with the latter.

`fn` directly represents λ-abstraction, which means it is limited to functions of one argument (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437019/anonymous-function-in-sml)). `fun` is convenient shorthand that allows you to [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a multi-argument function and bind a name to it with a single bit of syntax, so it's probably better to use `fun` whenever you want to do one of those things.

Comment: I would also vote for using `fun` in the general, as it is easier to read